# How to bind key-mapping for saving selected text to file in vim?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

In vim, I select a text in visual mode, and type `:w! ~/saved.txt`, actually vim will execute `:'<,'>w! ~/saved.txt`. like this:

[image]

The command will save the text into `~/saved.txt`. In another vim instance, I can use `:r ~/saved.txt` to read from `~/saved.txt` to the other vim.

This implement a global copy-paste on the same machine. I want to make this a vim-command/key-mapping, while I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: How about installing a proper Vim with clipboard support?

Comment: @romainl no, actually it's necessary, when I open 2 terminal and ssh to remote, and open 2 vim, only this feature can help me copy-paste cross two vim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple key-mapping:

```
vnoremap ,w :w! ~/saved.txt<cr>
nnoremap ,r :r ~/saved.txt<cr>
```

Replace `,w`, `,r` with your favour.

Comment: Use `x[nore]map` instead of `v[nore]map`.

Comment: Play little with Select mode. Based on `h Select-mode`, use `v[nore]map` is normally OK.    1. `When mappings and menus are defined with the |:vmap| or |:vmenu| command they
work both in Visual mode and in Select mode.`;     2. `- Printable characters, <NL> and <CR> cause the selection to be deleted, and
  Vim enters Insert mode.  The typed character is inserted.`

Comment: In select mode, printable characters are supposed to be inserted (replacing the selection). Your mappings start with `,`; clearly a printable character.

Comment: Now I use 'zy' for yank, 'zp' for paste, since 'y' and 'p' is more like vim key-mapping.